If the Super Majin Rymus is the supreme authority of the universe, why the great king demon ordered him to create the universe?
Dragon Ball Daima says the Super Majin Rymus is the supreme authority of the universe. But it also says the Great King Demon ordered him to create the universe (multiverse) . How can someone who is the supreme authority of the universe/multiverse be under the orders of someone else?
Who is the supreme authority of the universe (multiverse) , the Super Majin Rymus or the Great King Demon?

The universes did not exist yet when the demon king told them to create them. I don't know what question you are asking. It's like a king telling his subjects to create a duchy then assigning the subjects as dukes to administer the newly created region.
